# Why is this a parse error?

Tags: php, syntax

The following code

```
$t =   1 – (1 - 2);
```

yields:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 3` in php 5.2.3
and in 5.4 I get `Parse error: in <file> on line 3`

To me it seems like I'm subtracting one expression from another, which I would imagine is legal. Why is this a parse error?

Comment: That's the exact code and nothing else?

Comment: the expression before is closed with a semicolon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first "–" is an en-dash, but it should be a hyphen-minus like the latter one: "-". Replace it, and your code will work.